# regex pattern for common prefix

Tags: java, regex

I have pattern like `^(\d{3}.\d{2}.ABC|\d{10}.\d{6}.XYZ)$`

I want to match every word with

```
                             123.45.ABC
```

my problem is I have lots of extension like `ABC,XYZ,PQR` so I want to make my pattern like that the prefix `\d{3}.\d{2}.` common and then extensions.

I want something like `(prefix pattern) (extension)`

```
                  (\d{3}.\d{2})  (.ABC or .XYZ MORE EXTENSIONS)
```

I can `^(\d{3}.\d{2})(.ABC|.PQR |.XYZ)$` but it matches two group one is for digits and one for extension.

Comment: have your tried [A-Z]{3} ?

Comment: no can you explain what is it?

Comment: `(\d{10}.\d{6})((.ABC)|(.XYZ)|(.WED))`. I used regex OR - |. But I can  create another regex if this doesn't fit

Comment: @user3543851 - explained in the answer. :)

Comment: escape the `.` using `\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the extensions inside non-capturing groups. You can add any number of extensions in that non-capturing groups.

```
^(\d{10}\.\d{6}\.(?:ABC|XYZ))$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the beginning of the line.
- `()` Capturing group.
- `\d{10}` Exactly 10 digits.
- `\.` A literal dot.
- `\d{6}` Matches exactly 6 digits.
- `\.` Matches a literal dot.
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group. It won't capture anything but it does the matching operation.
- `ABC` Literal ABC
- `|` Logical OR operator.
- `XYZ` Matches the literal `XYZ`
- `$` End of the line.

Comment: @user3543851 do want the explanation?

Comment: `?:` is called non-capturing groups. It won't capture anything but it do a matching operation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like

```
^\d{10}\.\d{6}\.[A-Z]{3}$
```

In Java, with `matches` we don't need the anchors:

```
if (subjectString.matches("\\d{10}\\.\\d{6}\\.[A-Z]{3}")) {
    // It matched!
  } 
else {  // nah, it didn't match...  
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "1111.111.XYZ"; // can match with AAA, VVA, ASA etc.. if you want only ABC and XYZ, then Avinash's answer is the way to go..

    String s2 = "1111.111.ABC";

    System.out.println(s1.matches("\\d{4}\\.\\d{3}\\.[A-Z]{3}"));// [A-Z]{3} matches any capital letter exactly 3 times.
    System.out.println(s2.matches("\\d{4}\\.\\d{3}\\.[A-Z]{3}"));
}
```

O/P :

```
true
true
```